# Abaqus Python script -- Reading 'TENSOR_3D_FULL' data from *.odb file

Tags: python-3.x, abaqus

**What I want**: strain values LE11, LE22, LE12 at nodal points
**My script is:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# coding: latin-1

# making the ODB commands available to the script
from odbAccess import*
import sys
import csv

odbPath = "my *.odb path"   
odb = openOdb(path=odbPath)    
assembly = odb.rootAssembly

# count the number of frames    
NumofFrames = 0
for v in odb.steps["Step-1"].frames:
    NumofFrames = NumofFrames + 1

# create a variable that refers to the reference (undeformed) frame    
refFrame = odb.steps["Step-1"].frames[0]  

# create a variable that refers to the node set ‘Region Of Interest (ROI)’    
ROINodeSet = odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets["ROI"]

# create a variable that refers to the reference coordinate ‘REFCOORD’    
refCoordinates = refFrame.fieldOutputs["COORD"]

# create a variable that refers to the coordinates of the node 
# set in the test frame of the step        
ROIrefCoords = refCoordinates.getSubset(region=ROINodeSet,position= NODAL)

# count the number of nodes    
NumofNodes =0
for v in ROIrefCoords.values:
    NumofNodes = NumofNodes +1


# looping over all the frames in the step
for i1 in range(NumofFrames):

# create a variable that refers to the current frame
currFrame = odb.steps["Step-1"].frames[i1+1]

# looping over all the frames in the step    
for i1 in range(NumofFrames):

    # create a variable that refers to the strain 'LE'    
    Str = currFrame.fieldOutputs["LE"]                
    ROIStr = Str.getSubset(region=ROINodeSet, position= NODAL)

    # initialize list
    list = [[]]

    # loop over all the nodes in each frame
    for i2 in range(NumofNodes):

        strain = ROIStr.values [i2]

        list.insert(i2,[str(strain.dataDouble[0])+";"+str(strain.dataDouble[1])+\
        ";"+str(strain.dataDouble[3]))

    # write the list in a new *.csv file (code not included for brevity)


odb.close()
```

**The error I get is**:
    strain = ROIStr.values [i2]
IndexError: Sequence index out of range

**Additional info:**
Details for ROIStr:

ROIStr.name
'LE'
ROIStr.type
TENSOR_3D_FULL
OIStr.description
'Logarithmic strain components'
ROIStr.componentLabels
('LE11', 'LE22', 'LE33', 'LE12', 'LE13', 'LE23')
ROIStr.getattribute
'getattribute of openOdb(r'path to *.odb').steps['Step-1'].frames[1].fieldOutputs['LE'].getSubset(position=INTEGRATION_POINT, region=openOdb(r'path to*.odb').rootAssembly.nodeSets['ROI'])'

When I use the same code for VECTOR objects, like 'U' for nodal displacement or 'COORD' for nodal coordinates, everything works without a problem.
 The error happens in the first loop. So, it is not the case where it cycles several loops before the error happens.

**Question:** Does anyone know what is causing the error in the above code?

Comment: What's the purpose of the (not indented) first for loop? Here you will also have a IndexError, since your iterating over the number of steps with index i1+1. Also note that `NumofFrames = 0    for v in odb.steps["Step-1"].frames:  NumofFrames = NumofFrames + 1` could be reduced to `NumofFrames = len(odb.steps["Step-1"].frames)`

Comment: The second <# looping over all the frames in the step
for i1 in range(NumofFrames)> is redundant. It got there during copy-pasting the code.

Comment: As a step to debugging this, try printing out the results of `strain = ROIStr.values[0]` where the index `0` is hard-coded.

Comment: @Mechanician You have to get your results using position `ELEMENT_NODAL`

Comment: @David Thanks; Using ELEMENT_NODAL worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the reason you get an `IndexError`. Strains are (obviously) calculated at the integration points; according to the *ABQ Scripting Reference Guide*:

> A SymbolicConstant specifying the position of the output in the element. Possible values are:
>
> `NODAL`, specifying the values calculated at the nodes.
>
> `INTEGRATION_POINT`, specifying the values calculated at the integration points.
>
> `ELEMENT_NODAL`, specifying the values obtained by extrapolating results calculated at the integration points.
>
> `CENTROID`, specifying the value at the centroid obtained by extrapolating results calculated at the integration points.

In order to use your code, therefore, you should get the results using  `position= ELEMENT_NODAL`

```
ROIrefCoords = refCoordinates.getSubset(region=ROINodeSet,position= ELEMENT_NODAL)
```

With

```
ROIStr.values[0].data
```

You will then get an array containing the 6 independent components of your tensor.

---

**Alternative Solution**

For reading time series of results for a nodeset, you can use the function `xyPlot.xyDataListFromField()`. I noticed that this function is much faster than using odbread. The code also is shorter, the only drawback is that you have to get an abaqus license for using it (in contrast to odbread which works with `abaqus python` which only needs an installed version of abaqus and does not need to get a network license).

For your application, you should do something like:

```
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from abaqusExceptions import *
import visualization
import xyPlot
import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo


results = session.openOdb(your_file + '.odb')
# without this, you won't be able to extract the results
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=results) 
xyList = xyPlot.xyDataListFromField(odb=results, outputPosition=NODAL, variable=((
        'LE', INTEGRATION_POINT, ((COMPONENT, 'LE11'), (COMPONENT, 'LE22'), (
        COMPONENT, 'LE33'), (COMPONENT, 'LE12'), )), ), nodeSets=(
        'ROI', ))
```

(Of course you have to add `LE13` etc.)

You will get a list of `xyData`

```
type(xyList[0])
<type 'xyData'>
```

Containing the desired data for each node and each output. It size will therefore be

```
len(xyList)
number_of_nodes*number_of_requested_outputs
```

Where the first `number_of_nodes` elements of the list are the LE11 at each nodes, then LE22 and so on.

You can then transform this in a NumPy array:

```
LE11_1 = np.array(xyList[0])
```

would be LE11 at the first node, with dimensions:

```
LE.shape
(NumberTimeFrames, 2)
```

That is, for each time step you have time and output variable.
NumPy arrays are also very easy to write on text files (check out `numpy.savetxt`).